# Doxygen Latex output using MathJax to create a Matrix definition produces an error

Tags: matrix, latex, doxygen, mathjax

I'm trying to get Doxygen to create a latex file that contains a matrix defined using MathJax notation.
The matrix definition in question is this:

```
\f$\begin{bmatrix}n2 / (r - l) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & n2 / (t - b) & 0 & 0 \\r + l / (r - l) & (t + b) & - (f + n) / (f - n) & -1         \\0 & 0 & -(2 * f * n) / (f-n) & 0\end{bmatrix}\f$
```

I've included these lines in my doxyconfig:

```
MATHJAX_FORMAT         = HTML-CSS
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     = TeX/AMSmath TeX/AMSsymbols
```

and for good measure:

```
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = TeX/AMSmath
```

Latex fails to compile when it reaches the matrix giving the error:

> LaTeX Error: Environment bmatrix undefined.

Adding the line

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

to the doxygen generated file 'refman.tex' solves the problem but this is not a solution as this file is overwritten each time doxygen is run.

I would assume that the lines I've added to my '.doxyconfig' would solve this problem but they do not.

Comment: From the manual: "EXTRA_PACKAGES The EXTRA_PACKAGES tag can be used to specify one or more LATEX package names that
should be included in the LATEX output. To get the times font for instance you can specify
EXTRA_PACKAGES=times
If left blank no extra packages will be included.
This tag requires that the tag GENERATE_LATEX is set to YES." Probably you need EXTRA_PACKAGES=amsmath

Comment: Thank you, that's solved it. I had assumed that it needed a 'Tex/' before it because of the mathjax extension.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.